# Configuration with name 'debug' not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I am creating a library and [I am following this link to add the library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library). Based on the documentation, I added the following two lines. The name of the library is **calendarLib**:

```
 debugCompile project(path: ':calendarLib', configuration: 'debug')
 releaseCompile project(path: ':calendarLib', configuration: 'release')
```

I get the  **configuration with name 'debug' not found** error. I don`t know what to do.  Kindly help me.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this to your build file:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

because library projects only build the release build type as a default.

Alternatively you can add this to your defaultConfig:

```
defaultPublishConfig 'release'
publishNonDefault true
```

Make sure you also have the debug build type defined for your library project:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you also have the debug build type defined for your library project. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have flavors in the subproject or library, you need to write the flavor with debug in camel case. For example, if you subproject has flavor 'calender' and 'calendarLite', and you want to use flavor 'calendarLite':

```
debugCompile project(path: ':calendarLib', configuration: 'calendarLiteDebug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':calendarLib', configuration: 'calendarLiteRelease')
```